# Noun and article

Tags: nouns, articles

Can we use swim as a noun? 
There is a mistake in this sentence. 
The swim you took must have addled your brain more than I have ever thought. 
Article with swim?

Comment: Yes, I went for a swim the other day.

Comment: A dictionary would tell you the answer to this.

Answer (score 2):

We can use certain action verbs as nouns - I went for a walk/run/swim. In British English we can go for a sleep, or a 'lie down'. Also there are two toilet verbs that can be used as nouns in this way.